# How to use gradle flavor to choose between two Kotlin imports (Google vs Amazon Java billing library)?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, amazon-appstore

I have an existing Google Play Android app that uses the [Google Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) and I'd like to use the recently released [Amazon Appstore Billing Compatibility SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/apps-and-games/blogs/2023/03/integrate-iab-with-amazon-apps) that implements a compatible API.

Their guide suggests replacing Java/Kotlin lines as follows, and on first take it works well. Just replace:

```
import com.android.billingclient.api.*
```

with

```
import com.amazon.device.iap.billingclient.api.*
```

I already use the [Gradle flavor](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants) mechanism to slightly tweak the build (e.g. different store & support URLs), so in an ideal world, I could leverage that.  I.e. I have this in my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
flavorDimensions = ["appstore"]
productFlavors {
    google {
        dimension "appstore"
        buildConfigField "String", "ENCRYPTED_GOOGLE_IAP_KEY", "<removed>"
    }
    amazon {
        dimension "appstore"
        buildConfigField "String", "ENCRYPTED_GOOGLE_IAP_KEY", "ignored"
    }
}
```

and I've configured the dependencies in the same `build.gradle` so that only the appropriate library is available:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    googleImplementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0'
    amazonImplementation files('libs/appstore-billing-compatibility-4.1.0.jar')
}
```

So, what I'd really like to be able to do is to conditionally import the appropriate dependency, i.e. with a preprocessor, it would be something like this:

```
#if defined(amazon)
import com.android.billingclient.api.*
#endif
#if defined(google)
import com.amazon.device.iap.billingclient.api.*
#endif
```

but of course that's not a Java/Kotlin compatible approach.  I could copy my existing implementation into two folders and tweak just the import line, i.e.:

```
src/
|-- google/
|   |-- java/
|       |-- com/
|           |-- example/
|               |-- MyPurchaseCode.kt
|-- amazon/
|   |-- java/
|       |-- com/
|           |-- example/
|               |-- MyPurchaseCode.kt
```

but the code is identical except for that one line, so it will be a pain to maintain (*and, after all, isn't the point of the Amazon compatibility library that I can keep my existing code* :) )

Any suggestions on how I might do this?  I wondered about creating some sort of "wrapper" interface and then having 2 source files, located as above, that implement it. But they're big with [many classes](https://amzndevresources.com/iap/appstore-billing-compatibility/api-reference/4.1.0/index.html) and my understanding is that I'd have to clone the declarations.

Perhaps I'm overthinking this and there's some simple answer! *(I admit my Java / Kotlin knowledge has faded …)*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for instance define type aliases of the objects you're using in the main `MyPurchaseCode.kt` file. There will be two Kotlin files with such type alias, one for the `google` flavor and the second for the `amazon` one.

Let's take for instance the `Purchase` object: the type alias definition for google should be located here `google/java/com/example/` and will look something like:

```
package com.example
import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase
typealias Purchase = Purchase
```

and the one for `amazon` should be located under `amazon/java/com/example/` and look like:

```
package com.example
import com.amazon.device.iap.billingclient.api.Purchase

typealias Purchase = Purchase
```

You can now add additional typealias for all the other common objects.

Your `MyPurchaseCode.kt` can be located under `main/src/java/com/example`.

Hope this helps

*Response*: This was great, thank you!  *(TIL Kotlin's `typealias`)*. The final solution has one gotcha but works well enough.  Specifically, `typealias` doesn't (always?) allow subtypes per [this report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34281/Access-nested-classes-including-sealed-class-subclasses-through-typealias) as [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957847/cannot-access-nested-type-through-typealias), so for the Amazon file I end up with:

```kotlin
typealias AcknowledgePurchaseParams = com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams
typealias AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener
typealias BillingClient = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient
typealias BillingClientStateListener = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener
typealias BillingFlowParams = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams
typealias BillingResult = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult
typealias BillingResponseCode = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponseCode
typealias QueryPurchasesParams = com.android.billingclient.api.QueryPurchasesParams
typealias QueryProductDetailsParams = com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams
typealias Product = com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams.Product
typealias ProductDetails = com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetails
typealias ProductDetailsParams = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams
typealias ProductDetailsResponseListener = com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetailsResponseListener
typealias ProductType = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.ProductType
typealias Purchase = com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase
typealias PurchasesResponseListener = com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener
typealias PurchaseState = com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase.PurchaseState
typealias PurchasesUpdatedListener = com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesUpdatedListener
```

and similar for Google, namely:

```
typealias AcknowledgePurchaseParams = com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams
typealias AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener
typealias BillingClient = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient

// etc
```

The gotcha is shown here, where it is necessary to alias sub-types explicitly:

```
typealias BillingClient = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient
typealias BillingResponseCode = com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.BillingResponseCode
```

This means my code in `main` had to change from:

```
BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
```

to:

```
BillingResponseCode.OK
```

which can be a little less clear, but I can live with that!